# start and control spring application with junit

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, selenium, junit

I want to automate some spring ui-tests with selenium and junit and therefore I have to start the spring application before the test and stop it afterwards. How can I run (start) a spring application within a static junit-BeforeClass method?

I tried the following:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp(){
    Application.main(new String[]{});
}
```

But then it's not possible to control the app (I have no reference and cannot stop it in AfterClass).

Comment: Why... Why not simply use the integration test support provided by Spring Boot, that will take care of all that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign a reference to your application in the setUp method to a static variable and then in `AfterClass` you can use this to terminate the application.

Unless your main method runs in background though, your `setUp` will never terminate so you'll need to start the app in a different thread, then keep a reference to that and terminate it at the end of the test